# Can't overwrite swap

Tags: mount, encryption, swap

i have ubuntu desktop 14.04 LTS and i want to encrypt my 7.88GiB swap partition (sda6).

Before encrypting i need to overwrite it, to make sure no important data is left on the partition.

For this, i disabled the swap partition with:

```
swapoff /dev/sda6
```

after that i verified that it isnt mounted:

```
swapon -s
```

and the summary is empty, so no swap mounted.

So if i try now:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/random | pv | dd of=/dev/sda6
```

i get following output:

```
0B 0:00:06 [   0B/s] [<=>                                                                                                                                                                                        ]
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0+2 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes (0 B) copied0 bytes (0 B) copied, 6,41465 s, 0,0 kB/s, 6,41463 s, 0,0 kB/s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was that the swap partition was in use by my regular OS. The solution was to use `SystemRescueCD` and boot it from the USB into memory using`docache`. Then i was able to overwrite the swap partition.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `dd if=/dev/random | pv | sudo dd of=/dev/sda6`
You aren't putting `sudo` on the last `dd`, this `sudo` is very important to give the permissions to `dd` for write in the disk.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey helio, i'm not on a computer right now but I did it with user root before. So this can't be the problem. Maybe it doesn't work because I disable the swap or because it has a special file-system. Linux swap

Comment: If do you ran as root. Why are you using `sudo` in the command?

Comment: I just typed it seperatly here for the question.

Comment: Then, what is the command that rou really ran? Did you ran it from the actual Ubuntu install or from LiveCD?

Comment: Actual ubuntu ! The same command but without that one sudo, running as root user

Comment: Did you tried it from a LiveCD? The swap partition may be locked.

Comment: that could be the problem. No, i have installed ubuntu from an USB? Can i use the same USB?

Comment: Yes, you can use the same USB.

Comment: ok what should i do? If i boot from it it will try to install ubuntu again? Or should i choose the `test ubuntu` option?

Comment: Choose `test ubuntu`